Output is not giving as Range(1,2,3,4) for val from1Until5 = 1 until 5 println(s"Range from 1 until 5 where 5 is excluded = $from1Until5")
I am executing
println("\nStep 2: Create a numeric range from 1 to 5 but excluding the last integer number 5")
val from1Until5 = 1 until 5
println(s"Range from 1 until 5 where 5 is excluded = $from1Until5")

But the o/p is not giving as below :

Step 2: Create a numeric range from 1 to 5 but excluding the last integer number 5
Range from 1 until 5 where 5 is excluded = Range(1, 2, 3, 4)

I tried using .toList function but the result is in List

What's your question?

If you want to print a collection in a specific way, take a look to .mkString

When you println an object in Scala it calls the toString method and shows the result. toString gives a simple representation of the object.
The toString method for Range gives the start and end of the range  because that is a simple way to describe the Range. It does not show every possible value in the range because there is no point, and it would be a huge string for large ranges.
If you want the output that you describe you can use the mkString method to create a string containing every value:
val range = 1 until 5

println(range.mkString("Range(", ",", ")"))

Note that the Range object does not contain all the values in the range, it just contains the start and end values and the type of range (to or until). The values specified by a Range are generated each time it is used in a map/collect/for or similar operation.
